# Souble Loop sheets and cells

Tags: excel, vba

please see below code. It works well but when I am trying to add extra loop over all sheets it gives me an mismatch error 13

This one works

```
Sub ostdat()

Dim val As String
val = InputBox(Insert)
For Each cell In Range("d2:d20")
If cell = val Then
cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 30
End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

But this one is not working, I have added only sheets loop

```
Sub ostdat()
Dim val As String
dim ws as worksheet
val = InputBox(Insert)
For Each ws In Worksheets
ws.Activate
For Each cell In Range("d2:d20")
If cell = val Then
cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 30
End If
Next cell
Next ws
End Sub
```

Basically what I am trying to do is to loop for all sheets and for all cells in column d and highlight all cells where value in cell meet the criteria from inbox (like "X130").

thanks
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub ostdat()
Dim val As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim c As Range

val = InputBox("Enter Number")
For Each ws In Worksheets
    For Each c In ws.Range("d2:d20")
         If c = val Then
              c.Interior.ColorIndex = 30
         End If
    Next c
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but still is throwing and error on 'if c = val then' line... :(
If I run it for column containing only numbers it works but problem appears when running for eg. "X102" or "S097".

Comment: What is val when it throws an error? try "if c.text = val then " to see if that works